# DynamoDB List type

Tags: android, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have problems understanding how to create a List for dynamoDB from my Android app.
I can store and load the `{
  "deviceId": "920e185a-63ed-46ca-bfca-f7a484ccb708"
}` from my app. But then to add the List and store my JSON objects as Map in the List is were i struggle.

The dynamoDB structure I want to create and populate looks like this in a JSON format:

`{
  "data": [
    {
      "heartBeatId": 1,
      "status": 1,
      "timeStamp": 1502183502711
    },
    {
      "heartBeatId": 2,
      "status": 1,
      "timeStamp": 1502183502812
    }
  ],
  "deviceId": "90563daa-63ae-40c5-905e-9e8c02f9624f"
}`

Then I want to populate the data List with the heartbeat object which is of Map type.
`{
  "heartBeatId": 2,
  "status": 1,
  "timeStamp": 1502183502812
}`
So im having problems defining the `@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "heartbeat")` class to create this structure.

I have been reading about the List and DynamoDBDocument here:

[DynamoDBDocument](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBDocument)

[DataType List](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes)

This how the `@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "heartbeat")` class looks right now.

I hope someone can help me define it or give me clues on how to proceed getting the structure i need.

```
package com.example.android.awsdynamoapp;

import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBDocument;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBTable;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "heartbeat")
public class HeartBeat implements DynamoDBTable {

private String deviceId;
private Map<String, Integer> data;
private List dataList;

public HeartBeat(){};
public HeartBeat(String deviceId){this.deviceId = deviceId;};

public HeartBeat(String deviceId, List dataList) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
    this.dataList = dataList;
  //  this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "deviceId")
public String getDeviceId() {
    return deviceId;
}

public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}
public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
    //this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}


public void setData(String deviceId) {
    Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();

}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "data")
public List getData() {
    return this.dataList;
}

@DynamoDBDocument
public static class JsonArray {
    private String heartBeatId;
    private String status;
    private String timeStamp;

}

/**
 * The name of the table to use for this class.
 */
@Override
public String tableName() {
    return "heartbeat";
}

@Override
public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of map object can be created as follows. The good thing in the above structure is that all the attributes in `data` is a Number. You can change it to String if needed as well. Based on your expected output, I have defined it as `Long`.

**Attribute Definition:-**

```
private List<Map<String, Long>> data;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "data")  
public List<Map<String, Long>> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Map<String, Long>> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

**Populate the data:-**

```
    MoviesWithData movies = new MoviesWithData();
    movies.setYearKey(1917);
    movies.setTitle("Tilte with list of map");

    Map<String, Long> dataMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    dataMap1.put("heartBeatId", 1L);
    dataMap1.put("status", 1L);
    dataMap1.put("timeStamp", 1502183502812L);

    Map<String, Long> dataMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    dataMap2.put("heartBeatId", 2L);
    dataMap2.put("status", 2L);
    dataMap2.put("timeStamp", 1503183502812L);

    movies.setData(Arrays.asList(dataMap1, dataMap2));
    dynamoDBMapper.save(movies, consistentDynamoDBMapperConfig);
```

**Sample output:-**

[image]

Comment: this works fine for creating the structure I need. Thanks alot. However I havent understood yet how to add a new object to the list. This way I overwrite it everytime i do .save()

Comment: Good. The OP was asking for samples to create the structure. I hope the answer resolves that issue. If you would like to update the data, you can use the low level API rather than mapper to prevent updating all the occurrence of the list attribute.